# tf.metrics.auc yielding very different from sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn

`tf.metrics.auc` is yielding very different values comparing to `sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score` for some situations.

I'm unable to determine what is the particularities of such situations, but I *was* able to procure a reproducible example:

Code and data downloadable from https://www.dropbox.com/s/ym2ptqaqw2qjite/minimal_program_AUC.zip?raw=1

**Code:**

```
import sklearn.metrics
from keras.models import Model, load_model
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np

def auc(y_true, y_pred):
    auc = tf.metrics.auc(y_true, y_pred, num_thresholds=65)[1]
    K.get_session().run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    return auc

model = load_model('Model.hdf5', custom_objects={'auc': auc})

X = np.fromfile('X_test(65, 80, 1292, 1).txt', sep=',').reshape(65, 80, 1292, 1)
Y = np.fromfile('Y_test(65, 1).txt', sep=',').reshape(65, 1)
batchsize = 45

evaluation = model.evaluate(X, Y, batch_size=batchsize, verbose=1)

predictions = model.predict(X, batch_size=batchsize, verbose=0, steps=None)

auc = sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score(Y, predictions, average='macro', sample_weight=None)

print('sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score: ', auc)
print('vs')
print('tf.metrics.auc: ', evaluation[2])
```

**Results:**

> sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score:  0.40476190476190477
>
> vs
>
> tf.metrics.auc: 0.2756012196724231

---

---

**Discussion:** I've read that `tf.metrics.auc` [is approximate](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/auc), and the higher the `num_thresholds` the closer to the ideal AUC it gets. (Change-Request/Side-note: My data only has 65 samples, so with 65 thresholds it's possible to compute the ideal AUC)
I've tested with several thresholds, and the outputted AUC value varies, but does not closely match `sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score`

**EDIT:** I also tested with `batchsize = X.shape[0]` so its computed in only 1 batch, and that didn't "fix" it

I did not find out if `sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score` is approximate or ideal.

### Question: What's up? Should we create a bug ticket?

**EDIT2:** Here is the culprit, the predictions are all almost 0.5, which causes the approximate nature of the TF AUC computation to be exacerbated

`0.506357729434967
0.4968412518501282
0.506340742111206
0.4976259469985962
0.5060197114944458
0.5054880976676941
0.506357729434967
0.5063252449035645
0.506357729434967
0.5028414130210876
0.49709421396255493
0.505968451499939
0.49766668677330017
0.506357729434967
0.506357729434967
0.5059878826141357
0.5063162446022034
0.5062981247901917
0.506357729434967
0.4971608519554138
0.506357729434967
0.506357729434967
0.4985077977180481
0.4981336295604706
0.5063574314117432
0.49704432487487793
0.506357729434967
0.5062510967254639
0.506357729434967
0.49734553694725037
0.49696335196495056
0.506357729434967
0.506357729434967
0.4975492060184479
0.49732962250709534
0.5019861459732056
0.4974926710128784
0.506357729434967
0.4975907504558563
0.49734383821487427
0.49705255031585693
0.506357729434967
0.5036844611167908
0.506357729434967
0.5041226148605347
0.5029517412185669
0.49785998463630676
0.5061197280883789
0.506357729434967
0.49714547395706177
0.506357729434967
0.506357729434967
0.5018795132637024
0.4972745478153229
0.49750152230262756
0.5063059329986572
0.49842190742492676
0.5164832472801208
0.496705561876297
0.49700644612312317
0.49824368953704834
0.5063083171844482
0.5031181573867798
0.49714842438697815
0.4966968595981598`

Comment: First of all, there is something terribly wrong if the AUC is < 0.5.
 As for the scores difference, I guess that's because in TF case (quoting documentation) "a linearly spaced set of thresholds is used", this means that if there are some predictions that are VERY close together, the score will be really off.
 I didn't try your code so I'm not so sure. Could you share the predictions so I can experiment directly on them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on what Qusai mentioned:

- AUC values smaller than 0.5 are not the expectation when evaluating a working classifier
- in the TF case (quoting documentation) "a linearly spaced set of thresholds is used", this means that if there are some predictions that are VERY close together, the score will be really off.

The classifier in this example was not really working, yielding the above predictions of nearly 0.5, when the label values are 0 or 1.

Plus, given the predictions are all very close together, the computed score was indeed way off.

Answer (score 0):

I believe using auc as a metrics in your training process (`model.fit(..., metrics=[auc],...)` means that it will calculate auc for each minibatch and gives average, which is not what auc works.

The roc_auc_score you use at the end using predictions and true labels is more accurate. You can validate the values by plotting the roc curve, as ~0.2 auc and ~0.4 can be easily distinguished.